# How to convert 1-d array into n-d array with considering NaN in elements?

Tags: python

I have a list like below, I want to break down this elements into n-dimensional based on the NaN in the value present.

Input:

```
[nan 0.1 0.4 0.6 nan 0.8 0.7 0.9 nan 0.3 0.6 0.8]
```

Output:

```
[[0.1 0.4 0.6]
 [0.8 0.7 0.9]
 [0.3 0.6 0.8]]
```

How to achieve this,

So far I tried,

```
l=[nan 0.1 0.4 0.6 nan 0.8 0.7 0.9 nan 0.3 0.6 0.8]

m_l=[]
t=[]
for val in l:
    if np.isnan(val):
        if len(t)==0:
            continue
        m_l.append(t)
        t=[]
    else:

        t.append(val)
m_l.append(t)
```

But I'm looking for improved solution.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? What sort of improvements are you seeking?

Comment: For this problem, I'm doing multiple append operation, I'm looking for some best `reshape`, so that I can avoid these costly operations.

Comment: Do you have/want a *list* or a *numpy array*?

Comment: In the question title, it's arrays, then you say list, then you post lists but then you are using numpy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want a squared array, thus each row have same amount of items:

```
l=[np.NaN, 0.1, 0.4, 0.6, np.NaN, 0.8, 0.7, 0.9, np.NaN, 0.3, 0.6, 0.8]
m_l2 = np.array(l).reshape((np.isnan(l).sum(),-1))[:,1:]
```

will output:

```
array([[0.1, 0.4, 0.6],
   [0.8, 0.7, 0.9],
   [0.3, 0.6, 0.8]])
```

Breaking the code apart:

```
m_l2 = np.array(l) #Convert it to a np array from list
nan_count = np.isnan(l).sum() #Counting the amount of NaN in the array
m_l2 = m_l2.reshape((nan_count,-1)) #Reshaping it according to the amoun of NaNs as rows, with auto infering column count
m_l2 = m_l2[:,1:] #Removing the first column, which is all NaNs
```

Comment: @MohamedThasinah `np.isnan(l).sum()` finds the number of `nan`, then reshapes the array to have that many rows, and finally shaves off the first column which contains the `nan`.

Comment: Broke it apart to rows with explanations.